# invoke the extension method of a class without using static class but by using class iteslf using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

I want invoke Method2 which is an extension method of a MyClass using MyClass type. I am wondering if this is possible or not.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    public static class MyClassStatic
    {
        public static void Method2(this ConsoleApp2.MyClass obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have called ex Method 2");
        }
    }

    public interface IClass
    {
        void Method1();
    }

    public class MyClass : ConsoleApp2.IClass
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have called Method 1");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {


        public static void CallWhereMethod()
        {


            var whereMethods = typeof(MyClass)
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Method2");


            Console.WriteLine(whereMethods.Count());
            // returns zero

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallWhereMethod();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a way for this, but it's hard a bit. If you don't forget to place a `this` keyword to your extension method parameter, C# compiler will emmit [ExtensionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to this method and this class. Knowing this, you are able to find this extension method and execute it:

```
var myClassType = typeof(MyClass);
var myClass = new MyClass();

var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach (var type in assemblyTypes.Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<ExtensionAttribute>() != null)
{
    var typeMethods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    foreach (var method in typeMethods.Where(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), inherit: false))
    {
        if (method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == myClassType)
        {
            // here you go
            method.Invoke(null, new object[]{ myClass });
        }
    }
}
```

If you unsure in which assembly to search for extension method, you may try to search **all**:

```
var allLoadedTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
```

**Please note:** reflection is **slow**. Really slow. Even you filter all of your types with `.Where(type => type.IsSealed)` or any other filter, it is still **dead slow**. If you have any other way to invoke the code in your extension method, you probably should use that way.

Comment: haha i was waiting for this, nice effort upvote. Though what if its in another assembly ? this will get ugly fast (or ugly slow my be more precise :) ).

Comment: @TheGeneral you are right, I have edit my answer to reflect this. Reflection is commonly a last resort and should be used when you absolutly understand what are you doing.

Comment: As of now this solution will work for me.. since used seldom use this feature... many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible, the only caveat is *.Net Reflection* doesn't understand the *Extension Method* syntactic-sugar of `this`.

*Remembering, that an extension method is a C# construct to save you a couple of printable-characters when calling a static class static method when given the first parameter (labelled with the `this` keyword)*

So in short, you'll have to target the static class and pass in the `MyClass` instance as the first parameter

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

var whereMethods = typeof(MyClassStatic)
                  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                  .FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.Name == "Method2");

whereMethods.Invoke(null, new object[]{ myClass } );
```

**Output**

```
You have called ex Method 2
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jnCUUn)

**Update**

> I don't want to use typeof(MyClassStatic). I want to use
> typeof(MyClass)

`Method2` is not a member of `MyClass`, and you can't force it to be as such in any way that I can think of.

Comment: I dont want to use typeof(MyClassStatic).. I want to use typeof(MyClass)